# add back button to first screen of navigation controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I know that a push segue automatically adds a back button so that the presentee can return to the presenter on click. What I want is for the back button to be available on the first UIViewController of the NavigationController (basically the only view controller in the chain that does not have a back button). How do I force add the back button?

I cannot simply add a custom image because **I want the exact same chevron that comes with the iOS back button**.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What should happen when the user tap the button?

Comment: Yes that doesn't make sense. You can do it adding a UINavigationItem but what's supposed to happen when they click back? Unless you add a UINavigationItem that serves as a menu or has any other functionality.

Comment: What is that button supposed to take you "back" to?

Comment: @Aaron, @LucaBartoletti if this is really a sticking point, @KonsolLabapen pointed it out: UITabBar programatically took me to DogVC, which as the leader of its Navigation thread has no back button. I want to streamline the user experience by adding a back button, which would take the user back to the caller/presenter. That's all. The big issue is I want the exact same chevron that iOS is using, and that has proven to be very difficult to get. So I figure forcing in the same back button should give me the chevron. I am free to modify the `@selector` after all.

Comment: The reason you can't get the exact. same. chevron. is because you're not using a navigation controller properly.

Comment: @learner did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (yet hackish) way to achieve this is probably adding a dummy view controller in the stack before the actual first one, so you will get a proper back button. Use dummy's `backBarButtonItem` to customize the button title if you need, and `-viewWillAppear:` to respond to the button being tapped.

Comment: This is a good answer. I thought about it, but was hoping for something more wholesome. +1. If I can't find better, I will use this and will customize the `@selector` of the back button.

Comment: I once tried to hack `UINavigationController`'s navigation item hierarchy to achieve something similar, but it turned out really bad. Had to implement the entire thing from scratch instead. Not really worth the pain, I should say.

Answer (score 0):

**What I want is for the back button to be available on the first UIViewController .... How do I force add the back button**

This whole thinking and logic is wrong. This is not how iOS UINavigationControllers work. You have a starting page (mainViewController) in a UINavigationControllers and from there you "move on" to something else. But you always come back to the main view controller. Just think about it, if you put a back button on the main view controller, where will the user go back to?

If you have a situation like this.

SomeViewController --> UINavigationController --> MainViewController

Once user is on SomeViewController and you take him to MainViewController which is part of UINavigationController then back button makes sense.

Just a FYI - you can easily drag and drop a UIBarButtonItem to any UINavigationController in Xcode and call it "Back". You will have to then connect that back button to another view controller.

Comment: The OP precisely says I want the exact same chevron. Unfortunately, there is "Back" for UIBarItem. There is "Rewind" which is not the image I seek. I seek the "Back" chevron.

Comment: This answer is presumptuous and learner is right in pointing to the lack of imagination on your parts. This is indeed a simple question and an explanation for what learner wants to do is irrelevant here. Still I can think of one: UITabBar programmatically leads to the page and a back button would take the user back to the presenter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't make sense but why can't you add a custom image? If all you want is "Back" chevron, can't you take a screenshot of this button and then put this image on your custom UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: I tried that it does not look quite the same. And apparently others have tried and it didn't work for them either.